# SymPy - Treating numbers as symbols

Tags: python, numbers, sympy, symbols, factorization

How can I treat numbers as symbols in SymPy?

For example, if I am performing a factorization with symbols I get:

```py
from sympy import factor
factor('a*c*d + a*c*e + a*c*f + b*c*d + b*c*e + b*c*f')
c*(a + b)*(d + e + f)
```

I would like the same behaviour when I am using numbers in the expression.
Instead of

```py
from sympy import factor
factor('2006*c*d + 2006*c*e + 2006*c*f + 2007*c*d + 2007*c*e + 2007*c*f')
4013*c*(d + e + f)
```

I would like to get

```py
from sympy import factor
factor('2006*c*d + 2006*c*e + 2006*c*f + 2007*c*d + 2007*c*e + 2007*c*f')
c*(2006 + 2007)*(d + e + f)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Symbol trickery to the rescue: replace your numbers with Symbols having a name given by the number. In your case you don't have to watch for negative versions so the following is straightforward:

```
>>> s = '2006*c*d + 2006*c*e + 2006*c*f + 2007*c*d + 2007*c*e + 2007*c*f'
>>> eq = S(s, evaluate=False); eq
2006*c*d + 2007*c*d + 2006*c*e + 2007*c*e + 2006*c*f + 2007*c*f
>>> reps = dict([(i,Symbol(str(i))) for i in _.atoms(Integer)]); reps
{2006: 2006, 2007: 2007}
>>> factor(eq.subs(reps))
c*(2006 + 2007)*(d + e + f)
```

Note: the `evaluate=False` is used to keep the like-terms from combining to give `4013*c*d + 4013*c*e + 4013*c*f`.

Answer (score 1):

Replace each constant with a unique symbol.
Factor the resulting expression.
Replace the unique symbols with the constants.

For your given case, something like this:

```
simple = factor('const2006*c*d + const2006*c*e + const2006*c*f + const2007*c*d + const2007*c*e + const2007*c*f')
simple.replace("const", '')
print(simple)
```

This should give you the desired output.  You can identify numeric tokens in the expression with a straightforward regex or trivial parser -- either of which is covered in many other locations.